# check addEditor(emailAddress) for non-google users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been able to use the addEditor(emailAddress) method to add editors to my google sheet.  It's great.  However, I only want to add the editor IF the e-mail provided is connected to a g-mail account.

Is there some way in sheets to identify if an e-mail address provided is NOT a g-mail user connected account, before running addEditor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. Before executing [addEditor(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addEditor(String)) code block, write a filter on top to check if the email passed ends in @gmail.com.

**Pseduocode:**

```
if(emailAddress not_ends with @gmail.com){
  rejectemail..close program
}else if(emailAddress end with @gmail.com){
  addEditor(emailAddress)
}
```

You can use the [endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) to filter the email addresses.

Comment: Noogui - Thanks for this suggestion.  It was a good solution to a somewhat simpler problem than I am having.  I'll explain further: 

Not all google user addresses have an @gmail.com domain.  Many of my potential users have organizational accounts that end in something other than gmail.com.  Still more potential users have a personal e-mail that is NOT a gmail, but is connected - or associated - with a gmail account. In either of these cases the e-mail address will end in any number of things that are not g-mail.com.  But google still recognizes them as google users.

Comment: I want my script to add the e-mail address to the list of editors ONLY if google recognizes the e-mail address as an actual google user.  Hope that's clearer.

Comment: That sounds rather complex.  In that case, you can't use my pseudocode since you're saying that even a non-gmail user is considered a google user.  You'd have to find another way of figuring this out then.